# if/else statement in Javascript with multiple intervals

Tags: javascript, if-statement, operators, intervals, multiple-conditions

I am having trouble creating an if/else statement with multiple variables which must match some threshold values and numerical intervals.

Here are the variables (they are numerical values entered by user through input fields with specific id-s):

```
var ValoareaGlicemiei = parseInt(document.getElementById("glicemiavalue").value);
var ValoareaGlicozilata = parseInt(document.getElementById("glicozilata").value);
var ValoareaGlicozilata1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("glicozilata1").value);
var ValoareaTTOG0h = parseInt(document.getElementById("0h").value);
var ValoareaTTOG2h = parseInt(document.getElementById("2h").value);
```

- ValoareaGlicemiei must be between 109 – 125;
- ValoareaGlicozilata must be between 6 – 6.4;
- ValoareaGlicozilata1 must be < 6;
- ValoareaTTOG0h must be < 109;
- ValoareaTTOG2h must be < 140;

All conditions must be validated before the PreDiabet function executes!

if/else statements in Javascript with the conditions below are not working!

```
if (ValoareaTTOG0h < 109 && 
    ValoareaTTOG2h < 140 && 
    ValoareaGlicozilata1 <= 6.0 && 
     (ValoareaGlicemiei >= 109 && ValoareaGlicemiei <= 125) && 
     (ValoareaGlicozilata > 6 && ValoareaGlicozilata <= 6.4) 
) {PreDiabet();}
else {somecode}
```

or

```
if ( (ValoareaGlicemiei >= 109 && ValoareaGlicemiei <= 125) && 
     (ValoareaGlicozilata > 6 && ValoareaGlicozilata <= 6.4) && 
      ValoareaTTOG0h < 109 && 
      ValoareaTTOG2h < 140 && 
      ValoareaGlicozilata1 <= 6.0 &&  ) 
       {PreDiabet();}
else {somecode}
```

What is wrong here with these conditions?

Comment: The first has weird brackets and the second one is missing a condition or has a && too many.

Comment: Your code should work except for the extra `&&` in the second one. The order of the tests doesn't matter.

Comment: Use `parseFloat()` for the inputs that can have fractions.

Comment: Specifically, ValoareaGlicozilata

Answer (score 0):

IDs cannot start with a number

You can use the unary operator to cast to number.

parseInt will drop your decimals

Your if is correct  - we do not need brackets when they are all ANDs

```js
const PreDiabet = () => alert("You are pre-diabetic");
document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const ValoareaGlicemiei = +document.getElementById("glicemiavalue").value || 0,
    ValoareaGlicozilata = +document.getElementById("glicozilata").value || 0,
    ValoareaGlicozilata1 = +document.getElementById("glicozilata1").value || 0,
    ValoareaTTOG0h = +document.getElementById("_0h").value || 0,
    ValoareaTTOG2h = +document.getElementById("_2h").value || 0;

  if (ValoareaTTOG0h < 109 &&
    ValoareaTTOG2h < 140 &&
    ValoareaGlicozilata >= 6 && ValoareaGlicozilata <= 6.4 && 
    ValoareaGlicozilata1 < 6 && 
    ValoareaGlicemiei >= 109 && ValoareaGlicemiei <= 125
  ) {
    PreDiabet();
  }
  else alert("All ok")
});
```

```html
<input id="glicemiavalue" value="115" />
<input id="glicozilata" value="6.1" />
<input id="glicozilata1" value="3" />
<input id="_0h" value="80" />
<input id="_2h" value="120" />
<input type="button" id="but" value="Calculate" />
```

Comment: With the lack of information from you I cannot test my code. "Gives error" is a very unhelpful comment. What error, When?

Comment: Your IDs cannot start with a number. Try my update

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I replaced my code with yours but no luck, not working!

// between and both included? Yes!

// ValoareaGlicozilata1 must be < 6; or <= 6? Must be < 6

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I will provide you with the source code in  a couple of hours!

Comment: I posted the page here and the code is available via page source.

https://www.metabolicanalysis.eu/TestareDIV2_newscript2_2.html

If you enter 90 in the Glicemia input field (leftmost) and 5 in the  Hb A1c, %: input field next to it and then you press the Calculeaza button, the path to Normal will turn red, if you enter 190 and 8 in the same fields the path to diabetes will become red.

It is the intermediary states between Normal and Diabetes, with multiple conditions who were causing me troubles!

ValoareaGlicozilata1 is the field under TTOGs.


Your help is greatly appreciated!